# `as` really required here?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

Here is my class which I create using a tutorial. I found that `interface` declared with `as` name. Is it really required? What is the purpose of that event it was already assigned.

My ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { ICurrentWeather } from '../interfaces'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-current-weather',
  templateUrl: './current-weather.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./current-weather.component.css'],
})
export class CurrentWeatherComponent implements OnInit {

  current: ICurrentWeather /*already assigned*/

  constructor() {
    this.current = {
      city: 'Bethesda',
      country: 'US',
      date: new Date(),
      image: 'assets/img/sunny.png',
      temperature: 72,
      description: 'sunny',
    } as ICurrentWeather /*is it required again?*/
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

defamation for Icon weather:

```
export interface ICurrentWeather {
  city: string
  country: string
  date: Date
  image: string
  temperature: number
  description: string
}
```

Comment: Well, what happens if you remove it? Does it still compile? That would answer your question, wouldn't it?

Comment: No. it is not required. you can complied

Comment: looking more clarity / understanding on `as ICurrentWeather`

Comment: It might or might not be necessary. It all depends on how ICurrentWeather is defined. But you didn' say. If remoing the `as ICurrentWeather` doesn't cause a compilation issue, then it's useless. If it causes a compilation error, then it's necessary, and the compilation error will tell you why.

Comment: share `ICurrentWeather` definition

Comment: You do know that `this.current={whate:"wa"} as ICurrentWeather` would work as well right?

Comment: If `as ICurrentWeather` is required for this code to compile than it is most likely misused because it asserts the constant value is of type `ICurrentWeather` when it clearly isn't.

Comment: @Antoniossss no, it wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not required but it is just you telling the compiler that you know about the types better than it does and that it should not second guess you. In your code

```
current: ICurrentWeather
```

here you are declaring a typed variable `current` while

```
this.current = {
      city: 'Bethesda',
      country: 'US',
      date: new Date(),
      image: 'assets/img/sunny.png',
      temperature: 72,
      description: 'sunny',
    } as ICurrentWeather
```

while here you are casting an object to other type i.e this {
          city: 'Bethesda',
          country: 'US',
          date: new Date(),
          image: 'assets/img/sunny.png',
          temperature: 72,
          description: 'sunny',
        } object to same as of `current` variable type and then assigning it to `current`.

Check Typescript Type Assertion [HERE](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you have assigned values to all the properties of the object 'current', therefore it does not make any difference if you use ' as ICurrentWeather' or not.

If you do not want to assign value to any of the properties then 'as ICurrentWeather' type casting is required otherwise code will not compile.

Let's consider that 'description' property is not mandatory.

```
this.current = {
    city: 'Bethesda',
    country: 'US',
    date: new Date(),
    image: 'assets/img/sunny.png',
    temperature: 72
} as ICurrentWeather;
```

will work but,

```
this.current = {
    city: 'Bethesda',
    country: 'US',
    date: new Date(),
    image: 'assets/img/sunny.png',
    temperature: 72
};
```

will not compile. Note that 'description' property is not present in the object.

If you want to make the 'description' property nullable then you can declare the interface as

```
export interface ICurrentWeather {
    city: string;
    country: string;
    date: Date;
    image: string;
    temperature: number;
    description?: string;
}
```

Note that 'description' property has been appended with '?'
Now below code will also work because all required properties of the object have values assigned.

```
this.current = {
    city: 'Bethesda',
    country: 'US',
    date: new Date(),
    image: 'assets/img/sunny.png',
    temperature: 72
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no.
In this case as used to type casting. 
Its not required in this case, since you are providing all param of your interface.
In case you are not providing you need to use 'as' to cast it your type.
 Example -
Your interface

```
export interface ICurrentWeather {
  city: string
  country: string
  date: Date
  image: string
  temperature: number
  description: string
}
```

and you are not providing all value you can cast this to ICurrentWeather type

```
current: ICurrentWeather
this.current = {} as ICurrentWeather
```